# timekeeping initialization gives any indication?

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am using `getnstimeofday` in `console_unlock` function, which gets called very early during initialization. So early that even timekeeping will not be initialized so as to use `getnstimeofday`.

Is there any way to identify the precise moment to start using `getnstimeofday`. I mean, is there any global variable or any macro to check if timekeeping is initialized, so that I can start using `getnstimeofday`.

Comment: Are you trying to profile the kernel boot-up? maybe you can try [**getrawmonotonic()**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=getrawmonotonic). A bunch of macros designed as wrappers around it are available for reference [**here**](http://wiki.attie.co.uk/wiki/C/timer).

Comment: No, my intention is not profiling boot-up.
I got solution for this problem by continuously looping over current_kernel_time function until it gives some valid value which indicates, timekeeping has initialized.
Anyways, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user2067709 If you post your solution as an Answer to this Question page, I can award you the bounty.

Comment: I think that http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L50 could be usefull. If time keeping isn't suspended then you can start.

Comment: @VilhelmGray - Sorry but i needed a solution for this issue long time back and unfortunately didn't get any responses for long time and i only figured out a possible solution (may not be the best) and continued the development. I thought, it will be helpful to post my workaround if someone faces same issue. Thats why posted.

Comment: @MrK - Thanks, this is really a good way to do. But i followed a workaround and developed the code which is tested and released already. There was a deadline! But i appreciate your link.

Comment: @user2067709 Yes, I'm personally curious if someone can find the section of code in the Linux kernel that performs the actual initialization of the timekeeping functionality. Hopefully, another user will drop by and describe what actually happens in the kernel.

Comment: i think you can check the global variable jiffies. This variable is starting from 0 and added by the timer interrupt per HZ. Once the timer interrupt is UP, the gettimeofday also works. For description about timer mechanism, here is a good article but in chinese http://www.bluezd.info/archives/%E6%97%B6%E9%92%9F%E6%BA%90%E7%9A%84%E6%B3%A8%E5%86%8C